# Conditionally delete individuals from longtidunal data

Tags: r, tidyverse, longitudinal

I have a longitudinal data set where I want to drop individuals (`id`) if they do no fulfill the criterion indicated by `criteria == 1` at any time points. To put it in context we could say that `criteria` denotes if the individual was living in the region of interest at any time during.
Using some toy-data that have a similar structure as mine:

```
id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5)
time <-  c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3) 
event <- c(0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1)
criteria <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,0,0,1)


df <- data.frame(cbind(id,time,event, criteria))

> df
   id time event criteria
1   1    1     0        1
2   1    2     1        0
3   1    3     0        0
4   2    1     1        0
5   2    2     0        0
6   2    3     0        0
7   3    1     0        0
8   3    2     0        0
9   3    3     0        0
10  4    1     0        1
11  4    2     1        1
12  4    3     0        1
13  5    1     1        0
14  5    2     0        0
15  5    3     1        1
```

So by removing any `id` that have `criteria == 0` at all time points (`time`) would lead to an end result looking like this:

```
   id time event criteria
1   1    1     0        1
2   1    2     1        0
3   1    3     0        0
4   4    1     0        1
5   4    2     1        1
6   4    3     0        1
7   5    1     1        0
8   5    2     0        0
9   5    3     1        1
```

I've been trying to achieve this by using `dplyr::group_by(id)` and then filter on the criterion but that does not achieve the result I want to. I'd prefer a `tidyverse` solution! :D

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  # looking for the opposite (i.e. !) of criteria == 1 at least 1 time
  mutate(is_good = !any(criteria == 1)) %>%
  filter(is_good)
```

Comment: Worked with one modification.  Remove the acclamation mark. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you'd be willing to look into data.table's, which I recommend, it would be as simple as this:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df) # make it a data.table

df[ , .SD[ !all(criteria==0) ], by=id ]
```

See this page for a general introduction and an explanation of the `.SD` idiom:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html